# How to validate html textbox not to allow special characters and space?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, textbox

This is my html:

```
 <input type="text" name="folderName">
```

Here, I want to validate the textbox value by not allowing to key in special characters and space. But it should allow underscore.

How to validate this textbox?

Comment: Define “special characters”. Maybe better, specify the purpose in terms of what you wish to accept, rather than what is to be rejected. Then show your attempt at solving that problem and what shortcomings it has. Also make it clear whether you are looking for constraints expressed in HTML or client-side checks in JavaScript or server-side checks (in which language?) or some combination of them.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: Ok. Actually one folder will be created based on the text entered in the textbox. So that the restrictions are needed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may try to use this function:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function blockSpecialChar(e){
        var k;
        document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
        return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || k == 32 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57));
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frm" runat="server">
      <input type="text" name="folderName"  onkeypress="return blockSpecialChar(event)"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how to call this function?

Comment: its not allowing to enter anything?

Comment: Hi, I can't enter any letters into the textbox.. why?

Comment: @thevan:- Please check now!

Comment: yes. i can enter. but how to restrict space and allow underscore in that. I tried with the corresponding key code but its not working..

Comment: Thanks for this but, how can I block numbers?

Comment: would'nt be better to use regex excluding these simbols? rather then call the character code you could do like this: /[^"#$@%*,?\\<>\[\]|:']*/

Answer (score 7):

Try like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sub").click(function(){
var fn = $("#folderName").val();
    var regex = /^[0-9a-zA-Z\_]+$/
    alert(regex.test(fn));
});
});
```

This return `false for special chars and spaces` and return `true for underscore, digits and alphabets.`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7C5nP/

Answer (score 3):

You may try to use this function:

```
<input class="form-control" onkeypress="return ((event.charCode > 64 && event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123) || event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 32 || (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57));" id="name" formControlName="name" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="">
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery + jQuery Validation Plugin.
That will make it that easy:

This will allow the user only to type letters plus underscore

```
 <input type="text" data-validation="alphanumeric" data-validation-allowing="_">
```

Link to the jQuery Plugin:
http://formvalidator.net/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a javascript function that will do the validation.
You could find severals exemple around the web.
You could take a look on that website: [javascript-validation](http://mrbool.com/validation-in-javascript-emails-letters-and-empty-input-textbox/25472) and pay attention to the 
*Email Validation in Javascript* part (you will have to adapt a little).