# Allow Only AlphaNumeric in textbox using JQUERY

Tags: jquery, validation

I found following code here at :

[How to validate html textbox not to allow special characters and space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24774367/how-to-validate-html-textbox-not-to-allow-special-characters-and-space)

So Ive written this code for validation, but it is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="txtUsername" id="txtUsername" data-validation="alphanumeric" data-validation-allowing="_" value="">
```

Should I write any script to not allow special characters in textbox.

Comment: Please, create a single question each time. You are asking two questions in a single post. Separate these question as two posts.

Comment: ok i will create another post.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @Steaton, but still 1 special charackter is allowed: **€**
I fixed this problem.

```js
 $("#username").keydown(function (e){
  var k = e.keyCode || e.which;
  var ok = k >= 65 && k <= 90 || // A-Z
   k >= 96 && k <= 105 || // a-z
   k >= 35 && k <= 40 || // arrows
   k == 9 || //tab
   k == 46 || //del
   k == 8 || // backspaces
   (!e.shiftKey && k >= 48 && k <= 57); // only 0-9 (ignore SHIFT options)

  if(!ok || (e.ctrlKey && e.altKey)){
   e.preventDefault();
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="username" type="text" class="validate" name="username">
```

Answer (score 2):

This is HTML Part just need an ID

```
<input id="txtAlphaNumeric" type="text" />
```

Now the main logic of JQuery:

```js
 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#txtAlphaNumeric').keydown(function (e) {
       var k = e.which;
        var ok = k >= 65 && k <= 90 || // A-Z
            k >= 96 && k <= 105 || // a-z
            k >= 35 && k <= 40 || // arrows
            k == 8 || // Backspaces
            k >= 48 && k <= 57; // 0-9

        if (!ok){
            e.preventDefault();
        }        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtAlphaNumeric" type="text" />
```

Comment: (!e.shiftKey && k >= 48 && k <= 57 ) will stop special symbols but not all only 0-9 + shift ones

Answer (score 0):

Actually this allows for !"£$%^&*() symbols in the text. You need to modify the answer slightly to be:

```
<!-- Allow only alphanumeric -->
$('#username').keydown(function (e) {
    var k = e.which;
    var ok = k >= 65 && k <= 90 || // A-Z
        k >= 96 && k <= 105 || // a-z
        k >= 35 && k <= 40 || // arrows
        k == 8 || // Backspaces
        (!e.shiftKey && k >= 48 && k <= 57); // 0-9

    if (!ok){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

It prevents the shift key for the numbers.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function () {
   $('#txtNumeric').keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
           e.preventDefault();
        } 
        else {
            var key = e.keyCode;
            if (!((key == 8) || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 65 && key <= 90) || (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105))) {
               e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
});


<input id="txtNumeric" type="text" />
```