# Pre-validation of an input field in HTML

Tags: html, validation

Is there any way to validate inputs in the form using HMTL?

For example:

```
<input type="text" class="input-text error" 
 aria-required="true" placeholder="Enter your name *" 
 aria-invalid="true" required />
```

If user adds a special character to input, an error message saying "Characters are not allowed" should be shown below the input box.

Comment: I believe you need to incorporate javascript to achieve this.

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24774367/how-to-validate-html-textbox-not-to-allow-special-characters-and-space

Comment: I tried using pattern and content (in css) and it works but while adding a message in the content attribute i can't seen to add in 2 lines

Answer (score 1):

First of all, client-side form validation is the greatest feature coming with the HTML5. Client-side form validation helps you to ensure data submitted matches the requirements. To get more detail about it you can visit [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation).

### Important Note

Client-side form validation is an initial check, You should not use data coming from the form on the server side without checking it. It just a feature for good user experience. Because client-side validation is too easy to manipulate, so users can still easily send data that you do not want to on your server.

### Solution

In this question, the best solution is; using HTML attribute **pattern**. The `pattern` attribute defines a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp?retiredLocale=tr) the form control's value should match. To get more detail about `pattern` attribute you can visit the [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) page.

Below regexp you need.

> ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,12}$

It works like that;

- It should contains only alphanumeric.
- Minumum 5 and maximum 10
  character.

You can use below code to integrate it with input field.

```html
<form action="">
    <input type="text" name="name" required
           pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,12}" title="No special character">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Usually, to check inputs from html tags, you can create a javascript function to check your needs which is called everytime the user type in your input with the "onkeyup()" function.

The "onkeyup" keyword will trigger the function everytime user type in your field

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="myFunctionToCheck()">
<script>

    myFunctionToCheck(){
        //Here check your needs
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Okay so I could use a if/else function for checking the character but how do I show the error message below the field?
Should I be using innertext function?

Comment: You could create another hidden text field which show up when conditions are verified